# Getting error from CommunityGraphPlot

Tags: graphs-and-networks, web-access

#### Situation

I'd like analyse my web site with `CommunityGraphPlot` as follows:

Step 1: Define a function to scrape the all the webpages from expected website.

```
netScrape[url_] :=
  Union[Flatten[Thread[# -> Import[#, "Hyperlinks"]]& /@ Last/@ url]]
```

Step 2: Define a function to crawl the topology, down to the depth I want to dig.

```
webCrawler[rootUrl_, depth_] := 
  Flatten[Rest[NestList[netScrape, {"" -> rootUrl}, depth]]]
```

Step 3: crawl the website.

```
netFriends = webCrawler["http://bitwan.science", 2]
```

Step 4: Plot the community.

```
CommunityGraphPlot[netFriends]
```

#### Debug

I ran the above code, step1  through step4. However, I get a warning saying

> A graph object is expected at position 1 in EdgeList ...

Checking the data type of `netFriends` with `netFriends // FullForm`, confirms it is a list of rules.

I refer to *Mathematica* documentation on `CommunityGraphPlot`. I find it says that it's legal when using

```
CommunityGraphPlot[{v1 -> v2, v3 -> v4}, ... ]
```

#### My Question

I am confused by this situation. As the `netFriends` is a list of rules, why doesn't `CommunityGraphPlot[netFriends]` work?

Can anyone tell me why my codes produced the error I am seeing?

Comment: Can you  share the contents of the file *"friends.txt"*? Or at least an representative example of its form?

Comment: hello @rhermans , I have upload the data set.

Comment: Thanks, BTW `?dl=1` in the *Dropbox*  URL  for automatic download. I edited it for you. Please keep that file there forever, as this question will be visited by other users in the future.

Comment: `StringQ@friends` give `True`. You have imported the data as a single String, not a table of rules.

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e it arises from a simple mistake (syntax error, incorrect capitalization, spelling mistake) and is unlikely to help any future visitors, or else it is easily found in the documentation. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/10397).

Comment: hi @rhermans . My original problem wasn't caused by misused data type. I have post my original problem.

Comment: You have changed the question completely, I answered the original one, not the new one. Probably you should have asked a new question.

Comment: @rhermans you are right. now i will closed this post. Thanks your help very much. But, I've no idea how to close it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you have imported the data as a single String, not as table of rules as you expected. See that by evaluating `StringQ[friends]`.

One solution is this:

```
friends = Import[
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/hq8twoz2ct99kzr/friends.txt?dl=1"
 ,"Table"
 ]

CommunityGraphPlot[Rule[#1, #3] & @@@ friends]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]